# What happens when URLCache limit is reached

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, nsurlcache

I use URLCache to cache request response with a max capacity like this :

```
    let diskCapacity =  100 * 1024 * 1024
    let memoryCapacity =  100 * 1024 * 1024
    let cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: nil)
    URLCache.shared = cache
```

But I wonder what happens when the limit is reached. 
Will it not cache the new request ? or will it remove the old cache ? 
I could not find anything on the doc :/

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: automatically release the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in the cache will be released when the limit is reached.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All objects are deleted? Or only the oldest?